# SAS current date/timestamp

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am trying to get insert the timestamp, current date and current time into a table using macro, but values are not getting displayed as expected. Can someone help on this please?

Also i m trying to write the SQL return code and message, but it displayed nothing.

```
%MACRO INS;
 data _NULL_;

   call symput('currdatets',datetime());
   call symput('currdate',today());
   call symput('currtime',timepart(datetime()));


 %put  currdatets>  &currdatets;
 %put  currdater--2> &currdate;
 %put  currtime---2> &currtime;

run;

proc sql;

    CONNECT TO DB2 
  insert into table
    (entrytime, rundate, runtime)
  values 
    (&currdatets,&currdate,&currtime)

    DISCONNECT FROM DB2;
    QUIT;
    %PUT &SQLXMSG;
    %PUT &SQLXRC ;
%MEND;


WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference CURRDATETS not resolved.
currdatets>   &currdatets
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference CURRDATE not resolved.
currdater--2>  &currdate
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference CURRTIME not resolved.
currtime---2>  &currtime

WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference SQLXMSG not resolved.
&SQLXMSG
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference SQLXRC not resolved.
&SQLXRC
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first three macro-variables are not resolved because you specified the `%put` statements before the end of the `data _null_` step (i.e., before the `run;`). `symput` assigns values produced in a DATA step to macro variables during program execution.

Use `symputx` instead of `symput`. It does not change the result though, but
`symput` gives you a message on the log about the conversion, while `symputx` does not.  Moreover, `symputx` takes the additional step of removing any leading blanks that were caused by the conversion.

As for the two [SQL Pass-Through automatic macro-variables](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/sqlproc/p0xlnvl46zgqffn17piej7tewe7p.htm#p1cyzuadeotccqn1hwfdtmwejh2w) you will need to provide us with more information. I don't know if intended or not, but you seem to use an explicit Pass-Through connection. If so, you might be missing information to connect to the server (e.g., `connect to db2 (dsn= "xxxx")`).
The automatic macro-variables SQLXRC and SQLXMSG are reset after each SQL Procedure Pass-Through Facility statement has been executed. If they are not resolved it means there were not any.

By the way, according to the documentation, you may want to use [%SUPERQ()](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/macro/z0206633.htm) with SQLXMSG

> SQLXMSG contains descriptive information and the DBMS-specific return
> code for the error that is returned by the pass-through facility.
>
> Note: Because the value of the SQLXMSG macro variable can contain
> special characters (such as &, %, /, *, and ;), use the %SUPERQ macro
> function when printing the following value: %put %superq(sqlxmsg);

```
%macro ins();
data _null_;
    call symputx('currdatets',datetime());
    call symputx('currdate',today());
    call symputx('currtime',timepart(datetime()));
run;

%put  currdatets> &currdatets. | currdate> &currdate. | currtime> &currtime.;

proc sql;
connect to db2;
insert into table (entrytime, rundate, runtime)
values (&currdatets,&currdate,&currtime);
disconnect from db2
;
quit;
    
%put %superq(sqlxmsg);
%put &sqlxrc. ;
%mend;

%ins();
```

```
currdatets> 1966238593.2 | currdate> 22757 | currtime> 33793.19107
```

Comment: Thank you Kermit, can u advise how to format the date/time/timestamp ?

Comment: I am getting below error while executing the Insert 

NOTE: Line generated by the macro variable "CURRTIME".
438         3:54 PM
             _

ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a quoted string, a numeric constant, a datetime constant,
              a missing value, ), +, ',', -, MISSING, NULL, USER.

ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.

Comment: Also i m getting the error "ERROR: File UAT.table.DATA does not exist."

i have defined the Lib at the top as "libname UAT db2 ;"